# Diesel fuel valve outdoors: Gate, Globe, or Ball?

Tags: valves, piping, fuel

Real world question: We need to replace an internally failed (cannot shut) gate valve installed as a shut-off valve on a 2" Diesel fuel line exposed to weather (roof top) and operating at less than 20 psig. We're using a professional plumber on T&M to do the installation, but the boss has tasked me with planning the job to hold down costs. Would you recommend a globe valve, ball valve, or go back with another gate valve? For What It's Worth, the old valve was installed in 1972...

Comment: Quality is more important than the type of valve.

Comment: Plabn to do this with the tank nearly empty...

Comment: @SolarMike Oh, yes! We'll be draining the tank into drums. It's just a day tank, the main storage tank is in the basement.